# pdo Invalid parameter number

Tags: mysql, select, pdo, execute

My problem is the following

Y have two functions that are called from inside a function(method)

If the outcome of the first function is TRUE, the second function runs a select and an update query.

The second function runs a select with the query($sql) command
The update query uses:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute(arraywithvalues);
```

separatly, both functions work perfectly, but not when they are called both
in other words, by the time the second function needs to be executed, it will fail.
If I comment the first function out, it will execute fine?

**EDIT**

The update query

```
$tt = time() - 3600;
$w =array(NULL, NULL, $passw_new, $passw_key_new, $user_id);
$sql ="UPDATE table SET new_passw_requested =?";
$sql .=" WHERE passw_key_new='b02cdf33e46923de5a097c594e846764'";
$sql .=" AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(new_passw_requested) >= $tt";
$sql .= " AND id=?";
```

The actual functions are. 1)can_reset_passw() wich runs a select query, 2) reset_passw() wich performs one select and then an update.
Both functions work ok independantly like I said above.

**error: Found one**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id AND actief = :actief
Array ( [0] => SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens )
```

so something is messing with that

I try'd setting $stmt = NULL to clear resources, but that diddn't work.
Somehow the tokens from the first select are still in memory, I think

What could I do to fix this?

**solved**

The last error set me on the right path.
The dbabstraction class was holding de conditions in memory

thanks, Richard

Comment: What'S the problem you are seeing? What kind of queries are oyu executing? Etc. Please share some more details.

Comment: Could you please provide a little more code? Especially the part between `if ($rows)` and the second `$stmt = $db->prepare(...` seems to be important :-)

Comment: Are you calculating the timestamp twice? (Before each statement?) Maybe as time passes, the timestamp changes?

Comment: they run after eachother, it just checks if the timediffernce is still good. In this example, it's an houer.

Comment: What does `$modus` look like when it is put into the query?

Answer (score 0):

(This was solved some time ago by the OP and the solution edited in the question so it remained in the unanswered queue. Copied here as a community wiki answer to reflect the status, although the answer was very short. If anyone can make the answer more coherent they can edit here. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> The last error set me on the right path. The `dbabstraction` class was holding de conditions in memory